Can't open file passing as parameter to jar
If I run my project inside the IDE it works fine:
EXISTS c:\testvideos\[video] ролик\video.mp4
but if I run it in the Windows console I'm getting error:
NOT exists c:\testvideos\[video] ?????\video.mp
I tried:

setting chcp 65001
adding parameters -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
trying different encodings inside the app:
NOT exists c:\testvideos\[video] ?????\video.mp4 NOT exists c:\testvideos\[video] ?????\video.mp4 NOT exists c:\testvideos\[video] ?????\video.mp4 NOT exists c:\testvideos\[video] ?????\video.mp4

Here is the test code:
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TestFileArgument {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0];
//        String fileName = "c:\\testvideos\\[video] ролик\\video.mp4";
        try {
            checkFileExists(fileName);
            checkFileExists(new String(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251"));
            checkFileExists(new String(fileName.getBytes("windows-1251"), "UTF-8"));
            checkFileExists(new String(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.displayName()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void checkFileExists(String fileName) {
        if (new File(fileName).exists()) {
            System.out.println("EXISTS " + fileName);
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT exists " + fileName);
        }

    }

}


here is console launch string:
c:\Users\Ariloum\.jdks\openjdk-21\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -jar c:\testvideos\testFileArguments.jar "c:\testvideos\[video] ролик\video.mp4"
if I launch it out of batch file echo shows path correctly without question mark symbols instead of Cyrillic "???????"
Also it fails if filename contains two or more space symbols in a row "  ".
Is there any workaround for that?

Finally solved this by changing Windows 10 settings, there is one called
"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support".
It's in control panel language settings / administrative lang settings / change system locale.
With that turned on everything works fine directly with the cmd.exe or Runtime.exec
Also I've solved another Runtime exec file names issue handling names with double spaces in a row like this:
String command = "some.exe \"file      n    a m    e   \"";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.split(" "));


Powershell is your friend:
PS C:\Users\goose> [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
PS C:\Users\goose> Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 .\TestFileArgument.java
import java.nio.file.Files;    
import java.nio.file.Path;     

public class TestFileArgument {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "[video] ролик/video.mp4";        
        System.out.println(Path.of(fileName));
        System.out.println(Files.exists(Path.of(fileName)));
    }
}
PS C:\Users\goose> javac -encoding UTF-8 TestFileArgument.java
PS C:\Users\goose> java  TestFileArgument
[video] ролик\video.mp4
true
PS C:\Users\goose> 

UPDATE: Parameter being passed:
PS C:\Users\goose> [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding

PS C:\Users\goose> gci -Filter *.mp4


    Directory: C:\Users\goose


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        27/05/2024     11:35              0 два.mp4

PS C:\Users\goose> get-content TestFileArgument.java   
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class TestFileArgument {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0];
        Path p = Path.of(fileName);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(Files.exists(p));
    }
}
PS C:\Users\goose> java TestFileArgument два.mp4    
два.mp4
true
PS C:\Users\goose> 


you're not passing filename as parameter, I have maven project which has already setup in pom.xml to preform everything as UTF-8 and working fine if I hardcode external filenames inside it. problem begins if I compile it into jar and pass filename as argument.

yeah same error happens if I pass it as parameter in powershell running as .java class:
PS C:\testvideos> c:\Users\Ariloum\.jdks\openjdk-21\bin\java.exe -cp . TestFileArgument.java "c:\testvideos\[video] ролик\video.mp4"
NOT exists c:\testvideos\[video] ?????\video.mp4```

Yes I see. Shall investigate

Please see update for parameters

for some reason it's not working at my side. gci shows correct names but if I run the code error coming java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 0: ???.mp4

Can you open up a brand new Powershell session and go through these steps. In your case, create the tiny Java class shown in your editor in the current directory

Yeah I did all these steps, I even installed latest powershell and tried a few different java jdk's

Looks like I solved this with some Windows 10 tweak, I posted another answer, check it below. Thank you for help.

I'll try it with a jar. What is your preferred way of launching?
